# Enable Code Assist for OpenLayers Javascript Library

Tags: aptana3

I am trying enable code assist on OpenLayers JavaScript library and unable to get it work right.

After following the below instructions from Aptana JavaScript Library Support documentation I am able to see "Openlayers" on code assist but not any classes/methods or properties associated with it.

***Aptana JavaScript Library Support documentation Instructions:**

"Download the last stable release:OpenLayers-2.10.zip. Unzip the folder. Drop the folder named lib/OpenLayers into your project You will see API methods and classes shown."*

Based on the suggestion given from the thread *[Aptana Studio 3.3.1. Javascript code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765166/aptana-studio-3-3-1-javascript-code-completion)* , I tried to open my html document utilizing JavaScript editor to see if that would enable the code assist but it did not work either.

Based on the research I did, I found a thread *https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2726-cannot-add-sample-library* , that discusses this issue but did not find any proposed/solved solution.

Is there way to enable code assist for Openlayers. I would greatly appreciate any insight that   Aptana studio support staff could provide to help clarify this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Best,
Nathan